devexpress-treeList:How can the parent node not affect the selection of child components
I have a question.I used a datagrid with embedded child tables,However, when I select an item of the child table, it will be judged that the row of the parent table is selected, so that the child table is selected all. How to solve this problem?
If you select a row in a child table, the parent table does not affect the child table

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
